# What are the differences between the below feature selection methods?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

Do the below codes do the same? If not, what are the differences?

```
fs = RFE(estimator=RandomForestClassifier(), n_features_to_select=10)
fs.fit(X, y)
print(fs.support_)
```

```
fs = SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(), max_features=10)
fs.fit(X, y)
print(fs.support_)
```

```
fs= RandomForestClassifier(),
fs.fit(X, y)
print(fs.feature_importances_[:10,])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not the same.

As the name suggests, "recursive feature elimination" (`RFE`) *recursively* eliminates features, by fitting the model and throwing away the least-important one(s). After removing one feature, the next iteration may find the remaining features have changed order of importance.  This is especially true in the presence of correlated features: they may split importance when included together, so might both be dropped by your second approach; but in RFE, one gets dropped at some point, but then the other one appears more important in the following iterations (since it no longer splits its importance with its now-dropped companion) and so is kept.

Your third approach doesn't do any feature selection; it just prints the *first* (not top) feature importances (according to the model fitted on all features).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what about using `SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(), max_features=10)` it is equal to any of them?

Comment: Oh, for some reason that's what I thought your second code snippet was doing. Your second snippet actually doesn't do any intelligent selection, instead just printing importances of the _first_ (not top) 10 features (from the model fitted on all).

Comment: (I've edited the question and answer to add the `SelectFromModel` approach.)